# Array.Find does not return a value

Tags: c#, arrays

I am attempting to use `Array.Find()` to return a structure, from an array of structures, and assign it to a structure named Result. However, `Result`'s values never change from `null` (I ran it though the debugger twice). My code is posted below, can anyone please help me?

```
public void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string formName = textBoxName.Text;

    Info Result = Array.Find<Info>(Data, p => p.Name == formName);

    textBoxHeight.Text = Result.Height;
}
```

I'm trying to search an array of structs (`Info[]`) named `Data`, for an element `x` where `Info[x].Name` is the same as the values entered into another text box.

The debugger shows that it managed to find the element, but the element was never assigned to `Result`.

This is the declaration for the structure:

```
public struct Info
{ 
    string Name
    string Height
}
```

Comment: Something does not compute. You claim that the value of `Result` never changes from null, but `Result` couldn't ever have a null value because `Result` is of type `Info` which is a struct.

Comment: Are you sure that is the declaration of your struct? It does not have any public members.

Comment: Result can equal null.  Given the metadata returned by intellisense if the value is not found then `default(T)` is returned.  In this case `T==Info` and this has a defualt value of null.

Comment: So this leads to my next question, are you sure there is a matching value in the `Data` array?

Comment: @Steve `default(T) == null` when T is a class. `default(T) != null` when T is a struct.

Comment: @Greg you are correct My bad, I don't like using structs in general.  `Results.Height` can be null in two circumstances: 1)  When it is not initialized and/or set to Null  2) if result is not found.  So @dYanovski, are you sure the element is in the array or the `Result.Height` is not null.

Comment: Ah, it just clicked. I originally thought the OP was saying that `Result` was null, which isn't possible. But it would make sense if he means that `Result.Name` and `Result.Height` remain null.

Comment: @Greg my thoughts exactly

Comment: yes i made a mistake, I didn't set the members to public. However, I did that just now and it still didn't work.

What I meant by the Result being null is that its component values never changed from null (Result.Name, etc.)

Comment: Sorry, my first time asking questions, I'll make sure to provide better details from now on!

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me this should throw an error. I noticed name and height didn't have public modifiers so i wrote up a little test

[image]

As you can see the name property isn't available on the struct. I would try making name and height public and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: I declared name and height public just now, but the program still doesn't change the member values of Result. When I was running it through the debugger, it showed that the structure 'p' (inside the Array.Find) found the correct structure, and p was assigned its member values, but this was never transferred to Result.

Comment: it seems wierd that it would even compile. it also seems weird that in your code, Name property in p.Name is colored like a keyword. that should be a compiler error as seen in my picture. Could you try renaming the Info struct to MyCustomInfo and the properties to myName and myHeight and see what happens?

Comment: Same thing. Should i make the struct members public? I noticed that in your code you only write 'string name;', this may be why it is not accessible in your Main function

Comment: yes. I thought you had done that all ready. That was the point of my exercise. To show that in your example above, without the public modifier on name and height properties in your Info struct, they should be inaccessible.